# Any "DisplayName" option for ASP.NET MVC 5 Model class names

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

We have an app in development (EF6, Code First, even though the DB is "set in stone") where one table is called EMPLOYEES.  Our model has a EMPLOYEESRepository and we have many different EMPLOYEES views, etc.  Each view has headers: View EMPLOYEES, Edit EMPLOYEES, etc., obtained from model.GetType().Name.

Now management wants to call us all "Associates".

The DBAs aren't going to change the database, and there should be no need to.  But management wants the web pages to change.

I know that we can assign "DisplayName" attributes to properties, but there doesn't seem to be a similar option for the class.  My boss's idea is an all-hands change-the-code-by-hand, but that doesn't seem to be a good idea.

Is there a more ASP.NET/MVC/EF/Scaffold/etc way to display some sort of alternative name of the class?

Comment: You might be able to just rename it and do a find and replace in files to rename the entire solution in one go. If you had used edit/display templates or a HTML helpers of some sort for the type employee you could probably change it one singular location.

Comment: @br4d, that's what we wound up doing.  But we are constantly rerunning our scaffolding which changes everything back again.  We have CSS that keeps many of our changes, and one guy has written a match-replace program that replaces some things, but the word "Employees" matches too many places for that to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really should create a property in the view model to hold this kind of information. Like:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string ViewName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You can then set the name in controller dynamically using whatever common mechanism you prefer. What you are experiencing here is a consequence of tight-coupling. It's much better to address this kind of concern in a view model.

Comment: I think my problem with your answer is probably my own ignorance.  I don't know what you mean by a "view model."  My experience runs from Ruby's MVC pattern, which has significant similarities to Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC 5.  I think of MVVM as having to do with XAML, which I know nothing about. 

But even if I were to put a new property in my view, the moment we re-ran the scaffold, it would disappear.  So I think I must be misunderstanding your suggestion.

Comment: I think I understand. From a purists point of view, I can see why MVC makes sense. But, what I see as more effective in separating concerns, is the MVCVM pattern. That is, the M is your database, C the controller, V for the view and VM for the data that gets strongly-typed to the View.